# How to find out if installed server memory is registered (buffered) or unregistered (unbuffered)

Tags: linux, memory

Does anyone know a deterministic way how to find out, if the memory modules in a ***RUNNING*** Linux server are registered or unregistered?

I am aware of dmidecode and lshw but so far I did not find any way to differentiate between buffered and unbuffered memory mobuldes.

Comment: what type of hardware is it running on?

Answer (score 11):

`dmidecode -t 16 | grep "Error Correction Type:"`

Fully buffered: `Multi-bit ECC`
Unbuffered: `Single-bit ECC`
No EEC is `None`

`dmidecode -t 17 | grep "Part Number:"` -> google
Unfortunately, doesn't always yield a part number.

Comment: Hi, there are two different types of server motherboards: Intel S5000VSA and Intel SC5220HC(R). Thank you very much. This seems to be a good way, which works on all of our systems. :-)